# Edit IndexedDB sample

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I´m very noob with IndexedDB but I learned with the tutorials of a site(https://rolandocaldas.com/?s=indexeddb) without using 3rd libraries, the problem I have is that there is not yet a tutorial for Editing.

Can anybody help me with a example to edit a record without using 3rd libraries?

And if you can a example to delete a record?

I searched a lot but in other sites they use other libraries.

Thank you all.

Ps: Sorry for my english, its not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To edit an object, you can retrieve it from indexedDB, then change the object's properties, and then use [IDBObjectStore.prototype.put](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put) to store the modified object in place of the old object.
- To delete an object, call [IDBObjectStore.prototype.delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/delete) with the object's key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delete the previous record. Just use the put method to add the new object to the store using the same keyPath. This will replace the previous object